# -p and -o comm doesn't work together?

Tags: ps

I'm trying to get CPU usage of a process by,

`ps -p 12990 -o comm=comm,pcpu`

But that only print the command name (the process does exist), what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ps -p 12990 -o comm,pcpu
```

will show the `%CPU` and `COMMAND` columns for the process with PID 12990.

`-o comm=comm,pcpu` is being interpreted by your `ps` as "output the `comm` column, but rename the header `comm,pcpu`".*

If you explicitly want the `comm` header to be "comm", you'll either need to use two `-o` flags:

```
ps -p 12990 -o comm=comm -o pcpu
```

or put the renamed `comm` column at the end of the `-o` argument

```
ps -p 12990 -o pcpu,comm=comm
```

---

*From the `ps(1)` man page:

> The behavior of `ps -o pid=X,comm=Y` varies with personality; output may
>   be one column named "X,comm=Y" or two columns named "X" and "Y". Use
>   multiple `-o` options when in doubt.

Comment: This is the behavior specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ps.html): “The default header can be overridden by appending an equals sign and the new text of the header. The rest of the characters in the argument shall be used as the header text.”